# why first integer value turns zero after an if

Tags: c

after if triggers int1 value turns to 0
i had this problem alot even a simple sum function gives wrong answer and i dont know why help me please

```
int main(void)
{
    int num1;
    int num2;
    printf("Enter the first Numver:\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &num1);
    printf("Enter the scond Numver:\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &num2);

    if (num1 == num2)
    {
        printf("%d is equal to %d\n",num1,num2);
    }
    if (num1 = !num2)
    {
        printf("%d not equal to %d\n",num1,num2);
    }
    if (num1<num2)
    {
        printf("%d is greater than %d\n",num2,num1);
    }
    if (num1>num2)
    {
        printf("%d greater than %d\n",num1,num2);
    }
    if (num1 >= num2)
    {
        printf("%d greater or equal to %d\n", num1, num2);
    }
    if (num1 <= num2)
    {
        printf("%d greater or equal to %d\n", num2, num1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

when i put 4 and 3 it says 3 is greater than 0

Comment: `(num1 = !num2)` should be `(num1 != num2)`

Comment: `num1 = !num2`  ---   if `num2` is not zero, then `!num2` is zero.   So the result is setting `num1` to zero.     If `num2` had a value zero, then `num1` would be assigned to `1`.     This is different from `num1 != num2` which tests if th values are equal, but changes neither.

Comment: thank you mate. i am the king of noobs in programming right now

Comment: when posting about a run-time problem, as this question is doing, Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.  This includes posting which header files are being `#included`d

Comment: regarding: `if (num1 = !num2)`  This is an assignment statement, not a comparison.  Perhaps you meant: `if (num1 != num2)`

Comment: yes thank you that was the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`num1 = !num2` is grouped as `num1 = (!num2)`. In other words `num1` is assigned to `!num2`, which is either 1 or 0.

`num1 != num2` is the fix.